# Using methods across classes?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton

I have two classes, one being a timer which prints commands at certain times, the other being a GUI which includes a start button for said timer.
I'm trying to get the start/stop button in my GUI to be able to use the timer.start(); and timer.stop(); methods which are used in the TimeKeeper class.

I've searched all over this website and have read many Oracle docs, but am still unclear on how this would work in my case.

This is the full timer class:

```
package tests;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimeKeeper extends JFrame
{
private Timer timer;
private int delay = 1000; // every 1 second
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int counter = 0;
private int[] times = {};
private String[] commands = {};


public TimeKeeper()
{
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter = counter+1;

            if (counter == times[0]) {
                new SayText();
                SayText.say(commands[0]);
            }
            if (counter == times[1]){
                SayText.say(commands[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(delay, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start(); //MOVE THIS TO START BUTTON IN OTHER CLASS
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new TimeKeeper();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is a short form version of the GUI class

```
//package name
//imports

public class TwoPlayer {
//variable initializations

public TwoPlayer(){
//mainFrame specs

//Jlabel

//Some JFields   

JButton button1 = new JButton("Start/Stop");   
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
  }); 

//Another button 
//Another button
//Another button

//JPanel creation

//add components to mainframe

}
}
```

Comment: Wrap the `timer.start()` method call in a `TimeKeeper` method of the same name. Then call the `start()` method on your `TimeKeeper` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your design is lacking from a little bit of, oh, well, design.

Let's take a step back for a moment, what right does `TwoPlayer` class have to modify the `TimeKeeper` class?  Realistically, none, that's not its responsibility. At the moment, all it wants to do is get the timer to start and stop.  It doesn't care how

Equally, all the `TimeKeeper` class cares about is managing the `Timer`.

This is good example of why you shouldn't extend from `JFrame`, it's locked you into a single use case, which has made it next to near impossible to extend or expand the functionality.

So, what's the answer?  Well, let's take a half step back and look how you might re-design this...

`TimeKeeper` is responsible for managing the `Timer`, to this end, we need to provide the ability for other classes to start and stop this `Timer` (there's probably other functionality it needs, but I'm sticking to basics).  Also, it should extend from something more flexible, maybe `JPanel`, this will make it easier to re-use and extend should you need to.

```
public class TimeKeeper extends JPanel {

    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 1000; // every 1 second
    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] times = {};
    private String[] commands = {};

    public TimeKeeper() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(counter);
                counter = counter + 1;

                if (counter == times[0]) {
                    //new SayText();
                    //SayText.say(commands[0]);
                }
                if (counter == times[1]) {
                    //SayText.say(commands[1]);
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(delay, action);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

}
```

Now, we need someway for the player to interact with the `TimeKeeper`, to this end, we need a start/stop button.  You could use a `JToggleButton` or otherwise manage the state of an individual button, but for simplicity, I've used two...

```
public static class ControlsPane extends JPanel {

    public static final String START_COMMAND = "Start";
    public static final String STOP_COMMAND = "Stop";

    private JButton start;
    private JButton stop;

    public ControlsPane() {
        start = new JButton(START_COMMAND);
        stop = new JButton(STOP_COMMAND);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(start);
        add(stop);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        start.addActionListener(listener);
        stop.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        start.removeActionListener(listener);
        stop.removeActionListener(listener);
    }

}
```

Now, all this class does is provides two buttons (on a panel) and the ability to add/remove an `ActionListener` which be notified when one or the other button is clicked.

Notice, this class has no actual means by which it can interact with `TimeKeeper`, it's sole responsibility to is generate notifications when one or the other button is pressed, the responsibility for actually doing something is with someone else

Let's put it together...

```
TimeKeeper timeKeeper = new TimeKeeper();
ControlsPane controlsPane = new ControlsPane();
controlsPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case ControlsPane.START_COMMAND:
                timeKeeper.start();
                break;
            case ControlsPane.STOP_COMMAND:
                timeKeeper.stop();
                break;
        }
    }
});

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(timeKeeper);
frame.add(controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

So, we create an instance of `TimeKeeper` and `ControlsPane`.  We register an `ActionListener` to `ControlsPane`, which calls `TimeKeeper`'s `start` or `stop` method based on the event generated by `ControlsPane` and then we add the two panels to the screen...

This is a very loose example a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and 
[Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

You might like to take a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer, this is by far the best response to a question I've ever seen on this site. I fixed the problem already, and actually diversified the job assignments in a way similar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things disabled, I'd have an interface with, at least, a stop and start method, implement the interface on the Timekeeper class, implementing standalone methods to do the timer.start()/timer.start() and then pass the Timekeeper instance into the GUI as an interface.  Fairly straight forward, really, but then the GUI class can take ANYTHING you want to implement a start/stop functionality with.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way of using methods is to create an instance of a class, with a statement like

```
Timekeeper timekeeper = new Timekeeper();
```

in some class (like `TwoPlayer`). Then, within the scope of that variable, you can call the methods "on" the instance you have created, something like

```
// ...
timekeeper.start();
// ... other code in here
timekeeper.stop();
```

In addition, since I see that you have implemented ActionListener in your timekeeper class, you can pass the Timekeeper instance to a `setActionListener()` method for your button.

```
JButton button = new JButton("start timer");
button.setActionListener(timekeeper);
```

and then clicking the button will invoke the `actionPerformed()` method on that Timekeeper instance.

Be aware that the timer class, since it implements ActionListener, is then partly a GUI class. This just means that you can only use that class in a place where it makes sense to have it operated with a Swing Action.

Comment: The timekeeper instance could be a field in `TwoPlayer` and then the nested classes would have access to the variable. That would decouple the GUI relationship for `TimeKeeper`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if Timekeeper implements ActionListener, then it would only make sense to use Timekeeper in a program where it was being invoked by a Swing action. That ties the class to GUI classes, regardless of where it is instantiated. If one wanted to have a timer class that was useful without Swing, then it shouldn't implement ActionListener; instead, have some other class implement ActionListener and have it invoke Timekeeper methods.

Comment: Inner classes have access to outer class fields. So the anonymous inner class implementing ActionListener could call methods on TimeKeeper without TimeKeeper implementing ActionListener itself. That is what I was talking about.